# variable in ASP not working

Tags: asp.net, variables

Probably a simple answer to this.
In php, something like this would work fine.
Why doesn't this code work? The variable "Does not exist under the current context".

```
    <% string var = Page.Request.Form["DropDownList1"]; %>
    <title><% Response.Write(var); %></title>
```

Thanks

Comment: Works for me, although note the preferred separation of HTML and code into code behind. Also note that 'var' is a reserved word in .NET 4.0

Comment: Assuming asp.net (and not the older classic asp processor - your question was poorly tagged), that code should work, but the bigger issue is that you're bringing php's idioms to asp.net. I'd never write code like that for asp.net, but rather use placeholders. It's a whole different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable declared in a Content Control is scoped only within the Content Control

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227007/asp-net-mvc-what-is-a-the-scope-of-a-variables-inside-a-view/3263541#3263541) for an example